# PHP include inside an include

Tags: php, filesystems, include, directory

I have three php files. The "upper" file is a webpage (let's call it Sample.php). At the top of the page it does this:

```
<body>
<?php include("../Top.php"); ?>
//Webpage content
</body>
```

The Top.php file is a file with the menu and banner stored, for easy changing. The Top.php file has a line as such:

```
<?php include("ConnectToDB.php"); ?>
```

ConnectToDB.php is a file with some php code to connect to a database.

Here, the file system is ordered like so:

- RootFolder

  - ConnectToDB.php
  - Top.php
  - OtherSample.php
  - Articles

    - Sample.php

When I access Sample.php I get an error in the `include("ConnectToDB.php");` inside the `include("../Top.php");` statement. but if I have the file `OtherSample` with the `include("Top.php");` statement I will get no error and both Top.php and ConnectToDB.php work perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you must include("../ConnectToDB.php"); on Top.php as well

Comment: Sorry for explaining incorrectly, <?php include("ConnectToDB.php"); ?> is inside Top.php

Comment: yes, but you will need to add the ../ because the file path is relative to sample.php like radashk and Tobiask said

Comment: Yes, I am just looking for a way to do realtive path because more than one page in different directories access it. The relative path by radashk is not working.

Comment: I think you didn't untherstand what we said, did you do this include("/RootFolder/ConnectToDB.php") ?  change it to include("../ConnectToDB.php")   did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "include" statements actually ports the code into your page. So keep in mind that `include("ConnectToDB.php")` is executed from Sample.php, therefore the path is wrong.

The correct line of code would be: `include("../RootFolder/ConnectToDB.php")`

where `..` represent the whole dir structure after `"localhost/"` or whatever you are using.

Comment: Additionally, you should use `include_once()` top prevent loading the files twice…

Comment: It does not work. Though I guessed this was the solution, I get the error <code>No such file or directory</code> for the function include("/RootFolder/ConnectToDB.php") inside Top.php

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

`include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/RootFolder/whatever.php');`

to include files, this way you always have an absolute path for the include and it isn't dependent from where it is called.

Answer (score 1):

The path is wrong, by calling Sample.php all path belong to the base where the Sample.php is located. PHP searches for ConnectToDB in the wrong folder... 
Try ../ConnectToDB.php, as from the Sample.php file, this file i one folder above...

Better solution, use an absolute path!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. unfortunately,Samson's answer can't solve the problem for me.
You could try this one. It works fine for me.
Adding a file exist check then add the correct path in your Top.php
like this

```
<?php
if (file_exists("ConnectToDB.php")) {
    include_once("ConnectToDB.php");
}elseif(file_exists("../ConnectToDB.php")){
    include_once("../ConnectToDB.php");
}
?>
```

then you can access the correct path.